# S3 Bucket objects starting at a certain date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to get S3 objects from a bucket from a certain date on, otherwise i would just reread all the objects again and again. Is this option available without actually reading the object.
Any other suggesting, how to avoid rereading of objects?

Comment: You might also consider using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your actual use-case (that is, _why_ rather than _how_)? That is, _why_ you are seeking objects from a particular date? There might be an alternate way of achieving that goal.